# Getting WM/Picture using C# and WM Encoder SDK

Tags: c#, windows, windows-media-player

I was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction and/or provide a sample for me to look at.  I need to get the WM/Picture field inside a WMA file that I decode using WM Encoder and C#.  I have been able to get all the other tags fine, but media.getAttributeCountByType("WM/Picture", "") function always return 0. But Windows Media Player can display the picture correctly and I saw two hidden JPG files under the same music folder. MSDN don't provide much information about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

program chat voice with c#